# REGEXP_SIMILAR in Teradata

Tags: teradata, regexp-like

I am trying to take out names from a table where name does not contain characters or numbers.

```
Name Flag
Abc    0
124    0
£%     1
AB÷    0
17     0
*&     1
```

What function to be used in Teradata to achieve the desired result?

Best,

Comment: Yes, as the title says you could use REGEXP_SIMILAR to identify rows to keep. Be aware that REGEXP_SIMILAR has to match the entire string - you can think of it as always adding ^ before and $ after the supplied pattern string. Or you can use REGEXP_INSTR to identify rows to exclude.

Comment: `regexp_similar(str,'.*[^0-9a-zA-Z].*')` looks for any character not in the list